# excel choose and randomize

Tags: database, excel

I am still trying to figure this out. I have this data in one sheet in excel.

```
City         Risk Level
Facility 1  Extremely Low Risk
Facility 2  Very High Risk
Facility 3  Very Low Risk
Facility 4      Low Risk
Facility 5    Moderate Risk
Facility 6    Moderate Risk
Facility 7     High Risk
Facility 8     Extremely Low Risk
Facility 9     Very Low Risk
Facility 10     Low Risk
Facility 11    Moderate Risk
Facility 12   Extremely Low Risk
Facility 13     Very High Risk
Facility 14     Very Low Risk
Facility 15      Low Risk
Facility 16      Moderate Risk
Facility 17        Highly Moderate Risk
Facility 18       High Risk
Facility 19      Extremely Low Risk
Facility 20       Very Low Risk
Facility 21        Low Risk
Facility 22        Moderate Risk
Facility 23        Highly Moderate Risk
Facility 24        High Risk
Facility 25      Very High Risk
Facility 26       Extremely Low Risk
Facility 27        Very Low Risk
Facility 28         Low Risk
Facility 29        Moderate Risk

Risk Levels          Desired
Extremely Low Risk      3
Very Low Risk           4
Low Risk                4
Moderate Risk           5
Highly Moderate Risk    2
High Risk               2
Very High Risk          1
```

I would like to know if there is a formula that can choose the desired number of facilities from each risk level. For ex: 3 facilities with'Extremely Low Risk', then 4 facilities with 'Very Low Risk' , 4 facilities with 'Low Risk', 5 facilities with 'Moderate risk'and so on...I want the facilities to be picked randomly and I want the name of the facilities to be shown in columns, not in rows.

Please let me know how I could do this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=$E2,INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$30)/(($B$2:$B$30=$D2)*(COUNTIF($E$2:E2,$A$2:$A$30)=0)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$30,$D2)-COLUMN(A:A)+1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: HI Scott, this looks great, thank you for your help on this. But is there any way that the Facilities desired can be increased by rows instead of by columns? 

For ex:
Extremely Low Risk   Very Low Risk

Facility 1           Facility 7
Facility 5           Facility 30
Facility 10          Facility 20
                          Facility 23

and so on...

Please let me know if there is a way that I can do this.Thank you so much in advance.

Graciela